# Can visual studio 2010/2012 dynamic load properties during coding in c#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

Regarding the question,

Can visual studio load the properties in such matter :

for eg :

```
FieldsCollection fc = new FieldsCollection(Table.User):
fc.XXXX
```

where XXXX is from of list of properties generated from a dynamic source / location such as database?
Much like dynamic variables used @ MVC.

For eg: if Enum Table.User is selected, a list of fields belonging to the user table is shown.

Comment: Do you mean like EntityFramework?

Comment: for EF, any changes you made to the schema, you need to recompile EF model to reflect the changes. I want to dynamically load all the properties from a source or another dll outside the solution or project.